# http://localhost:8080 has not been whitelisted for client ID

Tags: google-analytics, google-api, google-analytics-api, google-developers-console

In following this tutorial: https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/embed-api/basic-dashboard/

I generated OAuth2 credentials, enabled the Analytics API and entered my credentials in the clientid field under the javascript that I'm running.

I am hosting this basic page locally with Python HTTP server. I added localhost in every format, including "http://localhost:8080" and "http://localhost" under the credentials' authorized origins and I am still getting the above error. I am stumped. None of the proposed solutions seem to be working as I've followed through with them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As it turns out, hosting the server online AND clearing cache fixed it.

Comment: No way to test on localhost?

Comment: You can use ngrok to test localhost

Answer (score 2):

Add "http://localhost:8080" to Restrictions- Authorized JavaScript origins. Add Google Analytics Api to your project and enable it. Then clear your browsing cache. It worked for me.